# Get IDs based corresponding value pairs uniquely

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Think of a table like this,

```
ID     Value    
100    1    
100    2    
101    1    
101    2   
102    1     
103    2   
104    1
```

Now i want to retrieve the IDs based on their corresponding value combination uniquely. (ie) 100 is having both 1 and 2 as values. 101 is also having 1 and 2. Now i don't want both 100 and 101. i want only one of them (either 100 or 101). similarly, i don't want both 102 and 104 since they both have values 1. i want only of them. Typically, my result should be as follows

```
ID
100
102
103
```

I want the IDs with corresponding value pairs uniquely.
i am using MYSQL. please help me write the query to find this.

Comment: I think you might need to explain the background to your situation to help us understand what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like some kind of relational division is going to be the solution. If there were always two values for every id this would be trivial but if there are variable numbers of values per id it is far more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
select
  min(id)
from (
  select 
    id, 
    group_concat(value order by value) as values
  from <table>
  group by id
) r
group by values
```

How this works:

- the subquery returns one row for each id, with an extra column that has all of the values (in sorted order, which is important for the next step)
- the outer query selects the minimum id for each set of values

Comment: That will get him the values, and he wants the IDs.. Also you need a group by in the subquery for the group_concat to work..

Comment: Well you just changed your answer.. Thats cheating ;)

Comment: @barsju I realized it was wrong and fixed it before you left your message.

Comment: I didn't know you could use order by inside the group_concat. Thats a nice touch.

Comment: It's actually the only way to make it work properly? If you add a ORDER BY after the GROUP BY it would not help, since you will be ordering the result after it has been grouped...

Comment: @MattFenwick : Thank you very much for help. To be frank, I didn't know about the group_concat concept before. A big head ache has been resolved for me. I have implemented it in my project and it is working fine. Thank you once again

Comment: @Matt is group_concat() a pre defined function in MS SQL?because when i used  group_concat() its saying not recognized build in function, sql server 2012